# Ninja Make system not accepting GENERATED command

Tags: cmake, ninja, cmake-language, cmakelists-options

I have a set of assembly files which should be compiled by a special compiler. After this it should be added to the library created by the compiler i have set in `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`. it was working fine with Mingw Makefile system but not working with Ninja Make.

Below is the code in cmakelists.txt

```
add_custom_target(
  special_asm
  COMMAND
    ${SPECIAL_ASM} ${src_file1}
    -I${INCLUDE_PATH} -o file1.o
  COMMAND
    ${SPECIAL_ASM} ${src_file2}
    -I${INCLUDE_PATH} -o file2.o
)
add_custom_target(special_asm_cmd COMMAND cmd.exe special_asm*.bat)
    
add_dependencies(special_asm_cmd special_asm)

add_library(
  mylib STATIC
  file1.o
  file2.o
  ${mylib_src})

add_dependencies(mylib  special_asm_cmd)

set_source_files_properties(
  file1.o
  file2.o
  PROPERTIES EXTERNAL_OBJECT true GENERATED true)
```

file1.o and file2.o are generated by different assembler. i have set the properties for these files also.

**Problem 1:**
custom target **`special_asm`** is not directly generating the object files. It is generating a batch script. That's why i have created one more custom target called **`special_asm_cmd`** to run the batch script which will generate the object files. The Mingw make system was directly generating the object file from **`special_asm`** but Ninja is not doing like that.

**Problem 2**
I have set the property **`GENERATED true`** for the special generated object files. But ninja is giving the below error. But Mingw Make was able to solve the dependency and no errors

```
ninja: error: '<path>/spt_init.o', needed by '<path>/libmylib.a', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Comment: Unlike to `Makefile` generator, where it is sufficient to know "the library `mylib` should be built **after** the custom target `special_asm`", Ninja need to know who (which target) exactly **produces the file** `file1.o`, which is needed for `mylib`. In CMake, producer of the file is searched by `OUTPUT` option of the `add_custom_command`. Documentation for that command contains [examples](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#examples-generating-files) of using generated files in `add_library`.

Comment: it works.. thank you@Tsyvarev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in using GENERATED here - cmake will know it, when you tell him, how you generate the files anyway.

```
add_custom_command(
  # Put generated files in binary dir, where they belong
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file1.o
  # Enumerate all dependencies.
  DEPENDS
      ${src_file1}
      ${INCLUDE_PATH}/header1.h ${INCLUDE_PATH}/header2.h etc..
  COMMAND
      ${SPECIAL_ASM} ${src_file1} -I${INCLUDE_PATH} 
      -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file1.o
)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file2.o
  DEPENDS
    ${src_file2}
    ${INCLUDE_PATH}/header1.h ${INCLUDE_PATH}/header2.h etc..
  COMMAND
    ${SPECIAL_ASM} ${src_file2}
    -I${INCLUDE_PATH}
    -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file2.o
)
add_custom_target(special_asm_cmd 
     # Enumerate the dependencies.
     DEPENDS 
         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file2.o
         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file1.o
     # Glob in add_custom target? Use glob with `file(GLOB ...`
     COMMAND cmd.exe special_asm*.bat
)

add_library(mylib STATIC
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file2.o
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file1.o
   ${mylib_src}
)
```

Cmake is a build system, specifically designed to *know* what comes from what. Files comes from other files plus commands. Tell cmake what files come from which commands and which source files - cmake will manage the dependencies and do all the rest like parallelizing the work and proper dependency tracking.